# Javascript - Rock, Paper, Scissors (odinProject) Helpppp

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I am having trouble with this assignment to create a game of rock, paper, scissors in javascript (Assignment from the odinproject.com). Whenever I use rock as my input it seems to work just fine. However, it does not work properly for when paper or scissors are entered. Please any help, suggestions, and advice would be greatly appreciate it. I am still very new at this and eager to learn more!

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```js
function userChoice() {
  const userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  return userChoice
}

function compChoice() {
  let compChoice = Math.random();
  if (compChoice < 0.34) {
    compChoice = "rock";
  } else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
    compChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    compChoice = "scissors";
  }
  return compChoice
}

function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  //Rock Choice
  if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else {
    return "Something Went Wrong";
  }
  //paper Choice
  if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Win! paper beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else {
    return "Something Went wrong";
  }
  //scissors Choice
  if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "You win! scissors beat paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Lose! rock beats scissors";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else {
    return "Something Went Wrong";
  }
}

console.log(playRound(userChoice(), compChoice()))
```

Comment: The first `else{return...}` skips the rest of the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the your `playRound()` function never gets past this:

```
if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
} else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
} else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
} else {
    return "Something Went Wrong";
}
```

This is due to the else you have at the end of that chunk of code. Since the `userChoice` is set to paper or scissors, it falls into that else and does not advance to the rest of the function. You could chain the ifs like so to fix:

```
if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
} else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
} else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
} else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Win! paper beats rock";
} else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
} else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "It's a Draw";
} .... 
rest of ifs 
....
else {
    return "Something Went wrong";
}
```

Comment: Thank You!! You have no idea how much time I just spent on this, glad it was an easy fix!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't enter `rock`, the first `else` statement will be executed, since none of the `if` or `else if` conditions will be true. It will return `Something went wrong` without performing any of the tests for `paper` or `scissors`.

All the other combinations should be additional `else if` statements, and you should just have one `else` at the very end.

```js
function userChoice() {
  const userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  return userChoice
}

function compChoice() {
  let compChoice = Math.random();
  if (compChoice < 0.34) {
    compChoice = "rock";
  } else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
    compChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    compChoice = "scissors";
  }
  return compChoice
}

function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  //Rock Choice
  if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  }
  //paper Choice
  else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Win! paper beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  }
  //scissors Choice
  else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "You win! scissors beat paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Lose! rock beats scissors";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else {
    return "Something Went Wrong";
  }
}

console.log(playRound(userChoice(), compChoice()))
```

Or you can use nested `if` blocks.

```js
function userChoice() {
  const userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  return userChoice
}

function compChoice() {
  let compChoice = Math.random();
  if (compChoice < 0.34) {
    compChoice = "rock";
  } else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
    compChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    compChoice = "scissors";
  }
  return compChoice
}

function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  //Rock Choice
  if (userChoice == "rock") {
    if (compChoice == "scissors") {
      return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
    } else if (compChoice == "paper") {
      return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
    } else if (compChoice == "rock") {
      return "It's a Draw";
    } else {
      return "Something Went Wrong";
    }
  }
  //paper Choice
  else if (userChoice == "paper") {
    if (compChoice == "rock") {
      return "You Win! paper beats rock";
    } else if (compChoice == "scissors") {
      return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
    } else if (compChoice == "paper") {
      return "It's a Draw";
    } else {
      return "Something Went Wrong";
    }
  }
  //scissors Choice
  else if (userChoice == "scissors") {
    if (compChoice == "paper") {
      return "You win! scissors beat paper";
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
      return "You Lose! rock beats scissors";
    } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
      return "It's a Draw";
    } else {
      return "Something Went Wrong";
    }
  } else {
    return "That's not a valid choice";
  }
}

console.log(playRound(userChoice(), compChoice()))
```

Comment: oooooh that makes sense! So simple yet I could not see it. Thanks a lot, I've spent hours at this!

Answer (score 1):

Try this: you need to remove the returns at the end of each if statement because they will happen unconditionally. You can return at the end to get that result if none of the other returns were run.

```
function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  //Rock Choice
  if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  }
  //paper Choice
  if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Win! paper beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  }
  //scissors Choice
  if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "You win! scissors beat paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Lose! rock beats scissors";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  }
  return "Something Went Wrong";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not break the flow by returning early.

```js
function userChoice() {
  const userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  return userChoice
}

function compChoice() {
  let compChoice = Math.random();
  if (compChoice < 0.34) {
    compChoice = "rock";
  } else if (compChoice <= 0.67) {
    compChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    compChoice = "scissors";
  }
  return compChoice
}

function playRound(userChoice, compChoice) {
  //Rock Choice
  if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Win! rock beats scissors!";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "Loser! paper Beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "rock" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else
  //paper Choice
  if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Win! paper beats rock";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "You Lose! scissors beats paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "paper" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else
  //scissors Choice
  if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "paper") {
    return "You win! scissors beat paper";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "rock") {
    return "You Lose! rock beats scissors";
  } else if (userChoice == "scissors" && compChoice == "scissors") {
    return "It's a Draw";
  } else {
    return "Something Went Wrong";
  }
}

console.log(playRound(userChoice(), compChoice()))
```